# How to get from and to dates from flatpicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flatpickr

I need to get `from` and `to`  using [flatpicker](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#range-calendar)

This is the setup:

```
$(".flatpickr").flatpickr({
    mode: "range",
    disableMobile: "true",
    altInput: true,
    altFormat: "d/m/Y",
    dateFormat: "d/m/Y",
    enable: [{
        from: new Date(dataSetCopy[0]),
        to: new Date(dataSetCopy[dataSetCopy.length - 1])
    }],..
```

And on close I need to get each date and save them into variables name like:

```
var dateStart = "12/3/2020";
var dateEnd = "31/3/2020";
```

I tried:

```
onClose: function(dateObj, dateStr, selectedDates) {
    $('body').removeClass('preventscroll');
    var dateStart = new Date(dateObj[0]);
    var dateEnd = new Date(dateObj[1]);
    dateStart.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    dateEnd.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

But I get

```
Tue Mar 31 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)
```

Tried to check [the docs](https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#range-calendar) but I don't understand how to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`formatDate()`](https://flatpickr.js.org/instance-methods-properties-elements/#formatdate-dateobj-formatstr) method from the [flatpickr instance](https://flatpickr.js.org/instance-methods-properties-elements/)

```js
$(".flatpickr").flatpickr({
  mode: "range",
  disableMobile: "true",
  altInput: true,
  altFormat: "d/m/Y",
  dateFormat: "d/m/Y",
  onClose: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
    var dateStart = instance.formatDate(selectedDates[0], "d/m/Y");
    var dateEnd = instance.formatDate(selectedDates[1], "d/m/Y");

    console.log(dateStart)
    console.log(dateEnd)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<input class="flatpickr">
```

Comment: strange, I get (Uncaught TypeError: instance.formatDate is not a function

Comment: @rob.m check the `flatpickr` version that you are using